# How to see the code (classes and methods) of a module such as sockets or pyHook?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to display the plain code of a module to see all classes and variables and methods and everything needed for it to operate fully

Comment: Well, just locate the module's source code and open it in your favorite code editor.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IDLE go to file: Open Module or Alt-M on windows; and type in the name of the module you want to see the source code of.
[image]